# using interface as a type

Tags: java, oop, interface

I read some Android code in the Fragment's section and trying to figure out the logic behind it. I have an Interface inside my class. I want to based on some conditions, the String value of the Interface's method changes. 
for instance with a `cond=false`, the code won't compile. I'm looking for a way with the same structure to make it work:

this is the Test class:

```
public class Test {

    InnerInterface interInstance;

    public interface InnerInterface {
        public String interfaceMethod(String s);
    }

    public void update() {
        String time = String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis());
        interInstance.interfaceMethod(time);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        boolean cond = true;
        Activity a = new Activity();
        Test t = new Test();

        if (cond)
            System.out.println(a.interfaceMethod("John"));
        else
            // this won't work of course
            t.update();
            System.out.println(a.interfaceMethod("Doe"));
    }

}
```

and here is the Activity class:

```
public class Activity implements Test.InnerInterface{
    @Override
    public String interfaceMethod(String s) {
        String actString =  s;
        return actString;
    }

}
```

Comment: Is this code compiling ?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: What's your specific question?

Comment: with the cond=true the code compiles, but in false condition I want to find a way to make it compile!

Comment: if/else without the braces `{}` is a bad practice. `if(...) { ... } else { ... }` is better. Also, if you want `t.update()` you can't have `interInstance` field in it null.

Comment: @BheshGurung python habits. sorry about that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about that?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    boolean cond = false;
    Activity a = new Activity();
    Test t = new Test();
    t.interInstance=a; //Add this line to your code

    if (cond)
        System.out.println(a.interfaceMethod("John"));
    else
        t.update(); //interInstance mustn't be null at this point
        System.out.println(t.interInstance.interfaceMethod("Doe"));
}
```